# breakline in sql server result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this result and i need to break it in 2 or more lines depending the { }...

this is my table: select distinct col1 from table1

the result for col1 is:

"{  CN_COND_ID:0,  CN_TYPE:1,  CN_VALUE:2,  CN_TARGET:1682,  CN_SOURCE:1684,  CN_DESCRIPTION:  }  {  CN_COND_ID:1,  CN_TYPE:1,  CN_VALUE:2,  CN_TARGET:1685,  CN_SOURCE:1684,  CN_DESCRIPTION:  }  {  CN_COND_ID:2,  CN_TYPE:1,  CN_VALUE:2,  CN_TARGET:1696,  CN_SOURCE:1695,  CN_DESCRIPTION:  }"

and i need to break it between each { }

i've tryed this below but without results.

```
select distinct replace(col1,'}', char(10) + char(13)) as col1 from table1
```

Comment: How did you test this?  If in SSMS, don't forget to switch from grid to text results.  The grid view suppresses line breaks.

Answer (score 1):

I would just write this as:

```
select replace(col1, '}', '}
') as col1
from table1;
```

However, I think your version should also add in a newline.

Answer (score 0):

First , switch from grid to text results , then run the query :

```
SELECT REPLACE (col1, '}', '}' + CHAR(13) ) as col1
FROM table1;
```